# how to display 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery

I just have a general question: I am sending a POST request to my Java backend application (I am using jQuery to send it) and basically it gives me the 500 Internal Server Error, but that's fine. The question is how do I display it as an alert, because I can see the error in the console but I want it to be visible (and possibly customised) to users. The error is caused when user is trying to add new record and posts it but it fails the validation on the server side. Here's the code for sending the request:

```
createCandidate: function (candidate, onSuccess){       
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ws/catservices/createCandidate',
            type : 'POST',
            async: false,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify(candidate),
            failure : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error" + textStatus);
            },
            success: onSuccess
        });
    }
```

And this is what I see in the console:

```
[10:12:52.762] POST http://localhost:8080/cat_prototype/ws/catservices/createCandidate [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 46ms]
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: There are 1000 ways. You can use a simple alert, a popover, a custom dialog and so on. If you want you can also do client side validation, so that you don't have to bother your server so often with validation (which it never the less should do!). What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ws/catservices/createCandidate',
        type : 'POST',
        async: false,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify(candidate),
        failure : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error" + textStatus);
        },
        statusCode: {
           500: function() {
             alert( "message" );
           }
        }
        success: onSuccess
     });
```

Comment: you forgot to close statusCode with "}" but apart from that worked perfect :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has two methods you could use. `complete` which will handle the response irrespective of it's status and `error` which will be called upon an error.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var error = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(error.Message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such `failure` key on `$.ajax`. [Check the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

It's called `error`, so simply replace `failure:` with `error:`.